# Why harris matrix is positive semi-definite

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm learning "Harris Corner Detector" algorithm,
and stuck here that why Harris matrix is positive semi-definite.

Since Harris matrix's trace is positive, so I can tell Harris matrix's two eigenvalues are all positive or one positive and one negative.

So, how to derivate Harris matrix is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix generated in the computation of the Harris corner detector is the structure tensor ([see here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_Corner_Detector#Development_of_Harris_Corner_Detection_Algorithm_[1])). The structure tensor `M` is a matrix created by the outer product of the gradient field `g` with itself:

```
g = gradient( image );
M = smooth( g * g' );
```

(with `smooth` the local smoothing applied).

Without any smoothing, `g * g'` would always have one positive eigenvalue and one 0 eigenvalue, by construction. You can see this by writing out the determinant of the resulting matrix, which is always 0, meaning that one of the eigenvalues must be 0 (their product is the determinant). The other one must be positive because the trace is the sum of two squares; since one eigenvalue is 0, the other eigenvalue must be equal to the trace.

The local smoothing adds together several such matrices (weighted addition). Adding together positive semi-definite matrices [leads to a positive-semi-definite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544139/sum-of-positive-definite-matrices-still-positive-definite): if `v'*A*v>=0`, and `v'*B*v>=0`, then `v'*(A+B)*v>=0`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can understand Harris corner detector algorithm better.